# How to wrap two elements into one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with wrapping two elements: label and input into one div. Can you help me how to do it right ? Thank you very much.

Example:

```
<label><label>
<input>
<label></label>
<input>
```

Should be:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label><label>
<input>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label><label>
<input>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').prev().andSelf().wrap('<div data-role="fieldcontain">');
```

HTML:

```
<label>Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />

<label>Surname: </label>
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through each `input` then club the input and the label and use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) like

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll('<div data-role="fieldcontain">');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gL536/)